# Does the constructor of HTMLTableElement get evoked when document.createElement is called?

Tags: javascript, html

Out of curiosity i decided to try and extend the HTMLTableElement to create a custom dynamic table and was wondering why my console log in the constructor isn't being evoked when i call createElement.

What am i missing...

```
class sudokuTable extends HTMLTableElement {
   constructor() {
      // Always call super first in constructor
      super();

      // create the caption for the sudoku puzzle
      console.log('this')
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't use `document.createElement('custom-element')` directly on [*customized built-in elements*](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/custom-elements.html#customized-built-in-element).

Rather you have to use `document.createElement('extended_element', { is: "custom-element" })`

```js
class sudokuTable extends HTMLTableElement {
  constructor() {
    // Always call super first in constructor
    super();

    // create the caption for the sudoku puzzle
    console.log('this')
  }
}

customElements.define('sudoku-table', sudokuTable, { extends: 'table' });
const your_elem = document.createElement("table", { is: "sudoku-table" });
```

Comment: So createElement can take a second parameter to handle this, cool!

Comment: ok so i was missing the customeElements part but for some reason it's still not console logging "this"

Comment: @PierreSmith you mean from the answer "code snippet"?